# Is it in any way possible to add an html elelment to a computed property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a navigation which uses computed properties to populate the li elements.

```
<ul v-for="link" in links">
    <li>
      {{ link.name }}
     </li>
</ul>


computed: {
  links(){
    return [
      {
        name: 'Link1',
      },
      {
        name: 'Link2',
      },
      {
        name: 'Link3',
      },
    ]
  }
 }
```

Now what if I want one of those links to have extra html element on it? For example let's say link2 links to a mailbox and I would like to have a span next to the name that counts the number of  emails.

eg:

```
<span class="email-counter">{{ messageCount ? `${messageCount.length}` : '' }}</span>
```

How can I apply this only to link2 without affecting the other links?
If I put it inside the li-tag, it will of course show up for all of the list elements.

Comment: You can add the array index if that helps: `v-for="(link, index) in links"`. Otherwise have meta-data that tells you for which link to put stuff in. See [Vue docs - v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for)

Answer (score 0):

When I run into things like this, I always find it works out better to abstract things a little and keep the parent neater. So, instead of putting lots of logic into the template, try to put as much of it into the original list, and additional components.

In this case I'd probably create a component to display a single link, and do something like this. It keeps everything cleaner, and makes it easier to make further changes in the future.

In this example I'm using Vue 3 and script setup as that's my default, but the idea is the same in Vue 2.

```
// navigation-menu.vue
<template>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <navigation-item v-for="link in links" v-bind="link" />
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>

<script setup>
// ... Import navigation-item

const links = [
    {
        label: 'Link 1',
    },
    {
        label: 'Link 2',
        count: 5,
    },
    {
        label: 'Link 3',
    },
];
</script>
```

```
// navigation-item.vue
<template>
    <li>
        {{ label }}

        <span v-if="count">{{ count }}</span>
    </li>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps({
    /**
     * The label to display on the menu item.
     */
    label: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    /**
     * A notification-style count to display beside the menu item.
     */
    count: {
        type: Number,
        default: null,
    },
});
</script>
```